# Force Type for FCGI PHP? Apache 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

With php 5.3 configured as DSO,  I am able to use the following in .htaccess to make .jpg files execute as php

```
<Files *.jpg>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

However, when I configure PHP as FCGI, this no longer works.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<Files ~ (\.jpg)>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .jpg
    Options +ExecCGI
    allow from all
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code rather :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

Or this one :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

These codes are alternatives to your code.